# C# Catch Unhandled Exception Down the Call Stack

Tags: c#, exception

I have a program that goes numerous functions deep to load a file and the chance for error in any of those functions is possible due to the possibility of loading a corrupted file.

I want to try catching any unhandled exception that's thrown while loading these files in the function that's calling the load function.

Is it possible to do this without putting a try catch in every single function called in the loading process?

```
try {
    var loadedFile = new LoadedFile(path);
    fileList.Add(loadedFile);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error Loading File");
}
```

Comment: Why would you put a `try-catch` in every function?

Comment: You *can* do it at the top-level caller but that's not the best practice. [You typically want to catch exceptions where the error occurs](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/231059/200248).

Comment: @Sylverac: Actually, I would say that in 90+% of the cases, you don't want to do that.  See an excellent blog post on the topic [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @Sylverac You most definitely *don't* want to catch exceptions where the error occurred. The resource you link to suggests adding context to the exceptions and re-throwing, which can sometimes be good, but the main point is to *handle* exceptions at a high level (where you can actually take a meaningful action).

Comment: You don't have to put a try/catch in every method.  Although try/finally tends to be important if you are going to catch exceptions like this.  But do note the drastic flaw in this code, what exactly do you expect your user to do with a ""Error Loading File" message?  You are completely obfuscating the cause of the mishap, he has no idea what he *could* do to make your program work.  Which is usually a sign that it should have been reported or re-raised by a lower-level method that knows more what went wrong.

Comment: exceptions will bubble up by default, unless there is something you can actually ***do*** about the exception where its created, I don't think there's a reason to use a try/catch block.

Comment: @sstan Great link. I rescind my comment but am leaving it up so the comment chain makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its possible. Simply surround the top most function call with a try catch. Any exceptions will be thrown all the way out. However you should catch it in the function it occurs and, assuming you can, fix the cause of the exception inside that function. If you can't you program must fail because it can not accomplish the task.

For example, if the file is corrupted the program should fail; if the file has a lock on it from another process you can wait until the lock is released (assuming it is ever released) before continuing or otherwise fail out.

Comment: Yes I feel silly. I assumed the catch would cause the breakpoint at the exception to not happen thus assuming the exception wasn't caught. I just tried it out on release outside of the debugger and found out it worked. The reason I wanted to catch the exception there is because it's not important if the file can't be loaded. It will just tell the user something is wrong with the file. The user can add as many files as he wants to the collection and they aren't vital to operation.

Comment: Well please feel free to mark as accepted answer. you'll want to make sure that where you catch doesn't stop the program dead which is what would happen if you caught it in the top most function call and not in some sort of loop. Though I'm guessing you are in a loop as you take input from the user(?) and based on that load a file into the collection to do something with.

Answer (score 2):

Unhandled exceptions "bubble up" the call stack until they are caught, or the application throws an unhandled exception error. You can put a `try...catch` block in your higher-level function, and it will catch exceptions thrown at the lower levels.

For example:

```
public void CatchEmAll()
{
    try
    {
        DoSomethingExceptiony();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle the exception
    }
}

public void DoSomethingExceptiony()
{
    throw new Exception("Uh oh!");
}
```

In this case, the exception thrown in `DoSomethingExceptiony` is not caught at that level, but bubbles up to the calling function `CatchEmAll`, where it is caught.

Side note: it's generally a bad practice to do `catch (Exception)` to catch any exception. It's better to understand what types of exceptions *could* be thrown by your code, and handle only those. For example, if you are loading a file, you might catch `FileNotFoundException` specifically, but not any and all exceptions.

Comment: "it's generally a bad practice to do catch (Exception) to catch any exception" - well, you have to do a `catch(Exception)` eventually, unless you want an unhandled exception to crash your program without letting the user know what happened. I agree you should handle specific exceptions better if you can, but your answer suggest trying to imagine every possible exception and handling only those, while the typical exception handling code has to fall back to catching `Exception` in order to react gracefully to any error that may occur.